# If I had a new economical theory, how could I share it with academical environments? I call it “algorythmic economy”

Tags: consumer-theory, decision-theory, soft-question

If I had a new economical theory, **how could I share it with academical environments?** I call it algorythmic economy.

I have made this same question on Quora.

https://www.quora.com/unanswered/If-I-had-a-new-economical-theory-how-could-I-share-it-with-academical-environments-I-call-it-algorythmic-economy

I am still writting the paper, and my intention is to prepare a proof-of-concept software to show easily demos to children, for them to not be lied anymore about wealthness.

Further than opinions, what I ask for is how can I share the paper and the software to truly interested people, with a genuine interest in the very deep nature of Economics.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Might be better for Academia:SE, but I'll give my two thoughts anyway.

The primary means of academic discourse is through peer-reviewed journal publications. Therefore, the simple advice is to write a paper and try to publish it in a (serious) economic journal. Here is a [list of journals](https://www.gate.cnrs.fr/IMG/pdf/cl_ranking_with_econ_correction.pdf) in decreasing order of reputation. There are different rankings used in the profession, but the broad classification of what constitutes a top 5 or an A-journal is not overly disputed in my opinion. Please do try to publish in an Economics journal. A lot of physicists or computer scientists publish papers claiming to revolutionize or reinvent Economics in non-economic journals like Nature of Science, probably get non-economists as reviewers and publish their claims without reference to the previous similar work in Economics.

As side-conversations during the publishing process you may also think of presenting at conferences, workshops, have private conversations / e-mails with academics in the field, or discuss your research on Twitter.

Comment: +1 but please remove the stack exchange this is not discussion forum. One can asks questions here but not start discussions.

Answer (score 1):

As elsewhere in academia, in economics as well, ideas are disseminated through:

- Workshops. These are usually organized by universities or other research institutions and if the workshop
- Seminars. These are similar to the above mentioned workshops but workshops are typically interactive whereas seminars are usually places where people can present their working papers in more lecture style format.
- Conferences. These are basically a large collections of workshops and seminars. In every sub-field of economics there will be constantly some conferences organized by universities or research bodies. Depending on the rules of the conferences they might allow contribution that has no (working) paper behind it yet but you should already have some results/theory to present.
- Preprints. When you have working paper ready you usually post it on a pre-print server such as SSRN or arXiv or NBER working paper series. Some preprints do some peer review some allow any paper to be submitted.
- Publication in a journal. Once the paper is finished you should try to publish it in journal.

Aside from the above there are informal channels such as social media.